# Making GIFs with ffmpeg: what does "transparency_color" do?

Tags: ffmpeg, png, transparency, gif

I've been making GIFs from PNGs using FFmpeg, using commands like the following:

ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -filter_complex "[0:v] split [a][b];[a] palettegen=reserve_transparent=on:transparency_color=ffffff [p];[b][p] paletteuse" -gifflags +transdiff -loop 0 -y OutputGif.gif

I've been trying (and failing) to understand what the "transparency_color=" option actually does. Apparently the default for this setting is 'lime', though a lot of examples I see online set "transparency_color=ffffff" instead. The official docs say that it will "Set the color that will be used as background for transparency". Based on that, I thought maybe what it specified was the color that should be displayed in a transparent pixel when viewing the GIF, if there's nothing "underneath" that transparent pixel; but that doesn't seem to be the case, unless most viewers just override that instruction or something. So does anyone know what the setting actually does? Thank you!

EDIT: I contacted a developer who helped implement the GIF support in FFmpeg, and my understanding is now this: The generated color palette contains 256 colors, chosen based on the input PNGs, which is used when mapping the input pixels to the pixels in the output GIF. When reserve_transparent=on, 1 of those 256 colors is chosen to be some value, which is "transparency_color", but this 1 "slot" in the palette is just used as a codename for transparency - only transparent pixels in the input PNGs will be mapped to transparent pixels in the output GIF, and transparency_color is just the color used to "store" this transparency data in the palette in the intermediate processing. So it's probably fairly unlikely that one would ever need to use the transparency_color option to change away from the default (which I believe is "lime"). Ideally, it's probably best to pick transparency_color to be a color that you *don't* have in the input PNGs, to avoid a naming clash in the palette between an actual visible color and the transparency codename. However as with the command in my question, I have often used transparency_color=ffffff even on PNGs with lots of ffffff white space, and nothing has gone horribly wrong, so maybe such a clash is resolved anyway somehow. In any case, it seems that indeed what transparency_color does *not* do is pick a color in the input PNGs that you want to end up transparent in the output GIF. To do that apparently the colorkey filter is the correct FFmpeg tool (E.g. https://engineering.giphy.com/modifying-ffmpeg-to-support-transparent-gifs/ ).

Answer (score 1):

The "transparent color" is the color that is mapped to transparent.

For example, if you have a web page with that image on it, and you use style sheets or absolute positioning or some other method to overlay the image on top of other items, everywhere in the gif that has that color, the items behind it (including the page's background) will show through instead of displaying that color.

Comment: I assumed that, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Using PNGs that I know have large areas of ffffff in them,  my resulting GIFs have ffffff in those areas, not transparency (checked with the color picker in GIMP).  Do you instead get the behaviour you describe? I found a dev comment (on https://tinyurl.com/pu6z2umf) saying "it's not a background color, it's a reference color code typically
used for the transparency optimization. It's a reserved entry such that
the encoder can perform a good compression.", which I don't understand, but it doesn't seem to fit easily with your interpretation?

Comment: If you have an example gif image that doesn't do what you expect, include it in your question.

Comment: @DDuf "a reference code" applies equally to ALL pixel-data bytes in a 256 color image. A pallette entry is (typically) 3 bytes in an array of 256 entries. Pixel data stores 1 byte which is the value of the pallette-array *index* not the color. The transparency is simply a color entry already in the pallette array, and a "transparency color" you are storing is just another index value from the pallette. PNG and GIF are different in that PNGs (depending on settings) can save a greyscale alpha channel which is stored separate from the "normal" image data. GIF transparency can't (or couldn't)